# Saving Multiple Objects with userDefaults Array in TableViewCell - Swift 5

Tags: swift, uitableview, persistence, uicollectionviewcell, nsuserdefaults

I'm implementing a Favorite feature inside a collectionview cell. The user should tap the favorite button in the cell to save the item. However, when the button is tapped to save the data from the custom object that populates the cell, only one object is being saved. If I tap to favorite another item, that one replaces the previous one, instead of being added to an array of favorites. Wondering what I'm missing here..

Here is the code:

Custom Object (Entity.swift)

```
struct MediaObject: Codable {
  let name: String
  var results: [Entity]
}

struct Entity: Codable {

var id: Int? 
var name: String? 
var kind: String?
var artwork: String? 
var genre: String? 
var artist: String? 

  private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {

           case id = "trackId"
           case name = "trackName"
           case kind = "kind"
           case artwork = "artworkUrl100"
           case genre = "primaryGenreName"
           case artist = "artistName"
       }


  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    id = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .id)
    name = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)
    kind = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .kind)
    artwork = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .artwork)
    genre = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .genre)
    artist = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .artist)

  }

}
```

View Controller.swift

```
class MediaViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


 var obj:MediaObject? = nil {
     didSet {
         collectionView.reloadData()
     }
 }


  @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
  @IBOutlet weak var sectionLabel: UILabel!

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

      if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
      flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 100, height: 90)
    }
}


  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return obj!.results.count   
  }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MediaCollectionViewCell

    if let obj = obj {
      cell.entity = obj.results[indexPath.row]
      cell.artistLabel.text = obj.results[indexPath.row].artist
      cell.trackLabel.text = obj.results[indexPath.row].name
    }

    return cell
  }



  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: 250, height: 205)
  }

}
```

And here is my MediaCollectionViewCell.swift class:

```
MediaCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


  @IBOutlet weak var artistLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var trackLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var favButton: UIButton!

  var favoritesArray = [Entity]()

  var entity:Entity? = nil {
    didSet {
      if let entity = entity,
        let artworkUrl = NSURL(string: entity.artwork!) {
        self.imageView.sd_setImage(with: artworkUrl as URL)
      }
    }
  }


  @IBAction func favButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    print("isFavorited")
  let encoder = JSONEncoder()
         if let encoded = try? encoder.encode([entity]) {
                  let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                  defaults.set(encoded, forKey: "entity")
              }

let defaultsData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "entity")

    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let loadedPerson = try? decoder.decode(Entity.self, from: defaultsData!) 

favoritesArray.append(loadedPerson)
print(loadedPerson)

print(loadedPerson?.count)


}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to save in the `UserDefaults`? Because I don't see `favoritesArray` getting saved anywhere. And it always has 1 entity because it is created inside the cell and only entity specific to that cell is added inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create a function that retrieves the saved entities
2. If there are no saved entities, save an **Array of Entities**, i.e [Entity]
3. Else **Append** the new entity to the already saved **Entities**

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

You've created the `favoritesArray` inside the `MediaCollectionViewCell`. Everytime a `cell` is reused, `favoritesArray` will be reinitialised, i.e. the `entity` added in it earlier will be lost.

That's the reason you always find a single `entity` inside it and that too of that particular `cell`.

**Solution:**

Instead of creating an extra `favoritesArray` inside the cell, try using *`closure`* to save the favourite entities. Here is the approach you can follow.

**1.** First of all use `class` instead of `struct` and add a **`isFavourite`** property inside the `Entity` model, i.e.

```
class MediaObject: Codable {
    let name: String
    var results: [Entity]
}

class Entity: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var name: String?
    var kind: String?
    var artwork: String?
    var genre: String?
    var artist: String?
    var isFavourite = false 

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "trackId"
        case name = "trackName"
        case kind = "kind"
        case artwork = "artworkUrl100"
        case genre = "primaryGenreName"
        case artist = "artistName"
    }
}
```

**Note:** There is any need to create `init(from:)` inside the `Entity` model. Use it when there is any special handling.

**2.** Now, inside `MediaCollectionViewCell` create a `closure` **`favouriteHandler`** and call it inside `favButtonPressed(_:)`, i.e.

```
class MediaCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    //rest of the code...

    var favouriteHandler: (()->())?

    @IBAction func favButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        print("isFavorited")
        self.favouriteHandler?()
    }
}
```

**3.** Next, in `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` set the `favouriteHandler` to update the `isFavourite` status of `entity` and then save all the entities with `isFavourite = true` in the `UserDefaults`.

Use **`filter(_:)`** to get all the favourite entities.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MediaCollectionViewCell
    if let entity = obj?.results[indexPath.row] {
        cell.entity = entity
        cell.artistLabel.text = entity.artist
        cell.trackLabel.text = entity.name

        cell.favouriteHandler = {[weak self] in //here...
            entity.isFavourite = !entity.isFavourite
            let favourites = self?.obj?.results.filter{ $0.isFavourite }
            let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(favourites)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "entity")
        }

    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Ahh, this makes so much sense! Somehow after adding this, when I tap the favorite button the 'favourites' array returns nil..

Comment: Have you converted from struct to class?

Comment: Yes, and removed the CodingKeys.

Comment: Not the CodingKeys. You needed to remove the init.

Comment: Oh! Yes, I removed that too.

Comment: Updated the Entity model in answer. please check